# Specific WiFi missing on fresh win 10 install

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-configuration

Due to a HDD issue an old computer got a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, on a new HDD.

With no WiFi on the motherboard, a [ASUS USB-N53 Wireless N300 USB Adapter](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/USBN53/) is used to connect to a [ASUS RT-N56U](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN56U/) router.

On the old drive, using windows 7 and later Windows 10 via upgrade, it all worked fine, and on the other computer running the same hardware it's running fine.

The Router has one network running at 2,4GHz and one at 5GHz.
The computer can find any neighbor network available, just not the two from the router at home.

I've tried reinstalling the network adapter, restarting both computer, adapter and the router.
I've tried a mobile hotspot which did show up in the list and worked as intended.
I've also tried creating a hosted network on a computer with internet access (using the WiFi in question), which doesn't show up in the list either (but is tested and works on an android device).

The network is running perfectly fine, but can't be found by that computer.
*As in, I'm currently using the network with two other computers and three android devices without any problems, and have been doing so for the last couple of years. Three computers, counting the one currently having problems.*

Any ideas?

**Update**

So I used my mobile hotspot to let the computer run a few windows updates.
While it didn't update the drivers of the network adapter, after the restart it now finds the 2.4GHz network again.
Not quite sure what caused this, and why it isn't listing the 5GHz one, but now that it has access to internet, I'll run more updates.

**Update 2**

Further system updates solved the last problem of not finding the 5GHz network.

Comment: I suggest that you backup your router configuration, reset it, and verify if the network shows up once you do that.  If it still does not then something else is going on, that something, will require more information though to determine a soluton for.

Comment: @Ramhound Well... That didn't really make much difference unfortunately. It still works fine on all devices except this computer. What other information would be useful?

Comment: The adaptor works or something else works?

Comment: @Ramhound It still finds the other networks as I said, but I can't really try to connect to them since they are secure. I opened a mobile hotspot, and that worked fine, but it's not a good solution for my data plan. So I tried to create an AP from my other computer. That worked for the phone, but this computer couldn't find that network either in the list.

Comment: Your last comment, "It still works fine on all devices except this computer." is vague.  Edit your question and clarify that statement.  The adaptor being able to find other access points, is not relevant, my train of thought is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: @Ramhound, updated it. "All devices" being two other computers, and three android phones. Most connecting on the 2,4 network, and some on the 5GHz. I think it's pretty relevant, but please share your train.